# How to get the value from the for each loop in android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating database in the android and adding values in the database. While retrieving data, the data is successfully retrieved. When I get data in the for loop it contains 14 values. How can I separate these values?

```
dataBaseHelper db = new dataBaseHelper(this);
List<String> studentInfo = db.getContact(eid);
for(Iterator<String> i = studentInfo.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = i.next();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**In this code I have 14 values in item I want to separate each value. How to do this?**

Comment: this is basic programming knowledge...just loop through your list

Comment: am new kindly help me i tried but i cannot

Comment: by the way, the question title is a bit misleading

Answer (score 3):

nothing mind bending about this, its extremely basic

```
for(String student : studentInfo){
    Toast.makeText(context,student,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: here what is context?

Comment: context is your context...

Comment: my  problem is getting all datas in student ,,i need to get the each value separately

Comment: no where do you show any student info, all you show is a list of strings being returned from your database. The `studentInfo` variable only has a string (name I am guessing) for each student in the list.

Comment: ya ,,,but how to separate these values for example i have a coloumn "name" "id" "date" etc.... when student info give the value one by one ,,suppose if i want to get the name,,what can i do?

Comment: you need to create a `Student` class or something to hold all the info and create a list of Students instead of a list of Strings. thats as much as I can tell you with the code you have given

Comment: my problem is that only how to do this?

Comment: well then you need to read a book about programming/java then. how did you even get this far without knowing how to create a class?

Answer (score 0):

try putting them into an array

```
dataBaseHelper db = new dataBaseHelper(this);
List<String> studentInfo = db.getContact(eid);
for(Iterator<String> i = studentInfo.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = i.next();
  fields[i] = studentInfo.get(i).getValue();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: why do you need to do that, he already has a list of students...just loop through the list!

Comment: am getting error in this line fields[i] = studentInfo.get(i).getValue();

Comment: i declared as a string but i is integer